# trying to add two arrays and get a function object error

Tags: python, addition

I am trying to add these two three-dimensional arrays. I am getting the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\ablev\eclipse-workspace\matrix\matrix.py", line 88, in 
> print(np.add(matrix_one.matrix1,matrix_two.matrix2))
> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'matrix1'

Code:

```
def matrix_one():
    print("Enter your first 3x3 matrix: ")
    matrix1=[]
    for i in range(3):
            while True:
                row=input().split()
                row=list(map(int,row))
                if len(row) != 3:
                    print(f"Please enter 3 rows of 3 columns of\
numbers separated by a space: ")
                else:
                    break
            matrix1.append(row)
    
    print("Your first 3x3 matrix is: ")
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            print(matrix1[i][j],end=" ")
        print()
        

def matrix_two():
    print("Enter your second 3x3 matrix: ")
    matrix2=[]
    for i in range(3):
            while True:
                row=input().split()
                row=list(map(int,row))
                if len(row) != 3:
                    print(f"Please enter 3 rows of 3 columns of\
numbers separated by a space: ")
                else:
                    break
            matrix2.append(row)
    
    print("Your second 3x3 matrix is: ")
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            print(matrix2[i][j],end=" ")
        print()
print(np.add(matrix_one.matrix1,matrix_two.matrix2))
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What exactly did you have in mind when you wrote `matrix_one.matrix1`? As the error message indicates, this bit of code is problematic.

Comment: I want to add matrix1 which is in function matrix_one to matrix2 which is in function2

Comment: Perhaps your `matrix_one()` function should end with `return matrix1`

Comment: Is this not the correct format? Thank You!

Comment: You can only see and use variables inside of the `matrix_one` function if you are inside of `matrix_one`. From the outside you cannot access them.

Comment: I though there was a way to access them through funtion.variable. I guess I am wrong about this?

Comment: The return did not work ben, thanks though

Comment: Nevermind, I just did the return wrong. Thank You All!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way to get your code to work.

```
def matrix_one():
    print("Enter your first 3x3 matrix: ")
    matrix1=[]
    for i in range(3):
            while True:
                row=input().split()
                row=list(map(int,row))
                if len(row) != 3:
                    print(f"Please enter 3 rows of 3 columns of\
numbers separated by a space: ")
                else:
                    break
            matrix1.append(row)
    
    print("Your first 3x3 matrix is: ")
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            print(matrix1[i][j],end=" ")
        print()
    return matrix1
        

def matrix_two():
    print("Enter your second 3x3 matrix: ")
    matrix2=[]
    for i in range(3):
            while True:
                row=input().split()
                row=list(map(int,row))
                if len(row) != 3:
                    print(f"Please enter 3 rows of 3 columns of\
numbers separated by a space: ")
                else:
                    break
            matrix2.append(row)
    
    print("Your second 3x3 matrix is: ")
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            print(matrix2[i][j],end=" ")
        print()
    return matrix2
print(np.add(matrix_one(),matrix_two()))
```

Example run:

```
Enter your first 3x3 matrix: 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
Your first 3x3 matrix is: 
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
Enter your second 3x3 matrix: 
2 3 4
3 4 5
5 6 7
Your second 3x3 matrix is: 
2 3 4 
3 4 5 
5 6 7 
[[ 3  5  7]
 [ 7  9 11]
 [12 14 16]]
```

Comment: So pretty much, calling the whole function, and getting the function to return the variable? Thanks!

Comment: @user3316598 That's right. As you probably figured out by now, you cannot access the variables declared in a function in the way that you attempted. As a rule of thumb, the easiest way to access a variable declared within that function is to `return` that variable as a function output.

Comment: Great, Ill keep that in mind for the future, thanks alot!

Comment: @user3316598 Glad to help. If you want to access variables in the way that you attempted, you have to create your own [class structure](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: OK, got it, thanks

Comment: Sorry follow up: cant I just change the variable to global. Is there a reason why you do not want to do that?

Comment: @user3316598 Actually, that is indeed an option here; I didn't realize that this was the case before. So yes, instead of returning `matrix1`, you can declare `matrix1` global within the function and access it that way. That said, I consider bringing a variable outside of a function via a return to be more "straightforward".

Comment: K, great. Thanks again!

Comment: @user Sure thing. By the way, I’d appreciate it if you could “accept” my answer by clicking the checkmark next to the vote arrows.